# Issues with triangulation when creating a mesh to simulate shadows

Tags: unityscript, mesh, unity-game-engine, triangulation

I'm trying to achieve fake shadows using a script-generated mesh in a 2D game. I've created some diagrams to illustrate the effect I'm trying to achieve:

1) Begin with the simulated light source (the circle), and two objects representing an obstacle (wrapped in a BoxCollider2D, which will block the light and create shadows) and a boundary (actually consisting of 4 edge colliders):

[image: step 1]

2) Cast rays at each vertex (corner) on the obstacle, and add the hit.point of each raycast to an array, additionally adding the target vertex to the array if it encounters the boundary first. Also, cast a ray at each of the verts (corners) of the boundary, and store the Vector2D of those hit.points in the array: the array essentially represents all vertices which are "illuminated" (should be easier to understand from the images to follow - it should be noted that I forgot one vertex from the diagrams, but they should get across what I'm saying):

[image]

3) Create a mesh by triangulating this array of vertices, making sure not to join points that create triangles that overlap the obstacle, that join across the region of "shadow", or that overlap eachother. **This is where I'm stuck**. (I've left gaps between the triangles to illustrate their distinctness):

[image: step 3]

4) Then you'll have a mesh representing an area of illumination, and an area not occupied by the mesh which shows the background colour - essentially, an area of shade:

[image: step 4]

Without really any inkling of what to do, I essentially just added [this Triangulator script](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Triangulator) to my project (which works until step 3) - but that triangulates everything in bizarre ways:

[image: progress]

## I am so lost.

I explored using [Graham's Scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) to sort my points, but it seems as though this would just encompass all of the verts within the simplest convex hull or whatever and wouldn't create a mesh without intersecting the shaded area.

So at this point I'm super uncertain how to approach the issue further, so any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Could check how others have done it, I have list of unity 2D visibility sources here http://unitycoder.com/blog/2014/10/12/2d-visibility-shadow-for-unity-indie/ (see comments for more)

Comment: @mgear Thanks so much for the resource, that looks really promising.